# conformation email google forms empty cell does not return

Tags: forms, email

Confirmatio e-mail Google form works good when all question are filled in. However when a not required question is not filled, the confirmation mail returns the first answer of a next question.
In the code below var achternaam is not required. I tried already with an if statement to returns the value "n.v.t." (if (achternaam ==""); {achternaam == "n.v.t."}). Unfortunately this does not work either.

How to solve this problem?

```
    function Initialize() {
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();

    for (var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }

    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit")
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
    }

    function onFormSubmit(e) {
    var tijdstip = e.values[0];
    var voornaam = e.values[1];
    var achternaam = e.values[2];
    var email = e.values[3];
    var wn = e.values[4];

    if (achternaam ==""); {achternaam == "n.v.t."}

    var emailTo = email;
    var subject = "Bevestiging";
    var emailBody = 
    "Beste " + voornaam + ",\n\n" +
    "Je hebt onderstaande gegevens naar ons verzonden \n" +
    "Met vriendelijke groet,\n\n" +
    "Technische Commissie\n\n" +
    "AchternaamTijdtip afmelding: " + tijdstip + "\n" +
    "Voornaam; " + voornaam + "\n" +
    "Achternaam; " + achternaam + "\n" +
    "e-mailadres; " + email + "\n" +
    "Wel of niet? " + wn + "\n" +
    "--------------";

    /**
     * Un-comment this to use it for debugging
    */
    //  for (var i in e.values) {
    //    Logger.log("" + i + ":" + e.values[i]);
    //  }

                MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo,subject,emailBody);


    }
```

Comment: Problem can be solved fully by using array. See script below made by Amit Agarwal, see http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884/#premium. Here below his script:

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be solved fully by using array. See script below made by Amit Agarwal, see http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884/#premium. It works great! Here below his script:

```
    /* Send Google Form by Email v2.0 */

    /* For customization, contact the developer at amit@labnol.org */

    /* Tutorial: http://www.labnol.org/?p=20884 */

    function Initialize() {

    var triggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();

    for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }

    ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();

    }

    function SendGoogleForm(e) 
    {  
    try 
    {      
    // You may replace this with another email address
    var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

    // Optional but change the following variable
    // to have a custom subject for Google Form email notifications
    var subject = "Google Docs Form Submitted";  

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var columns = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
    var message = "";    

    // Only include form fields that are not blank
    for ( var keys in columns ) {
    var key = columns[keys];
    if ( e.namedValues[key] && (e.namedValues[key] != "") ) {
    message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "\n\n"; 
    }
    }

    // This is the MailApp service of Google Apps Script
    // that sends the email. You can also use GmailApp for HTML Mail.

    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

    } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
    }

    }
```